# AWS - Network Load Balancer - Dynamic scaling based on the Request count per target

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-auto-scaling, nlb, cloudwatch-alarms

I'm having an application hosted in a EC2 Instance and I'm trying to create auto-scaling for my application.

I tired first with the **Application Load Balancer**, added SSL to the ALB & added listners and it suits my needs & Added dynamic scaling by creating my **custom alarm** with the **Request Count Per Target** metric.

My application uses **client certificate - mTLS authentication** (correct me if I'm wrong). What happened here is that the ALB rejects the client certificate and it didn't reaches my server. so we are back at level zero and started again with the Network Load Balancer.

I configured everything required for the NLB and added dynamic scaling. Here in the Network Load balancer I'm **unable** to create alarm with the request count per target. I created alarm with active flow & new flow count but the graph doesn't seems to reduce when there a new instance spinned and started serving the requests.

So my question is can we create a custom metric by which i can add or remove instances based on the **count of request** hitting each server's?

else can we use the ALB itself and do some routing to send the **client certificates (mTLS)** to the Instances and do my authentication in server?

Comment: To answer only part of your questions: Unfortunately ALB does not currently support mTLS.  You have to use a network load balancer for that.

Comment: Hope I have mentioned that already in my question itself, so that only I came back to NLB. Do you have any suggestion on the other questions?

Comment: A target group associated with a NLB doesn't give you a *Request Count Per Target* metric. Alarms on `Active Flow Count` and `New Flow Count` won't help as they're overall count on NLB instead of per target count. You can look at `CPU Utilisation` metric in the target group.

Comment: @RahulSharma This doesn't answers my question. I  know there is no direct option in NLB like ALB, my question is there workaround to achieve like that.

Comment: Remove the certificates at the ALB level, TLS must be terminated at the EC2 instance level in order for mTLS to work.